# Integrate json values into another file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to update an existing json file from values in another json file using jq in a bash shell.

I've got a settings json file

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": "Warning"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "./logs/log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Settings": {
    "DataServerUrl": "https://address.to.server.com",
    "ServerKey": "1f969476798adfe95114dd28ed3a3ff"
    "ServerTimeZone": "Mountain Standard Time",
    "MaxOccupantCount": 6
  }
}
```

In an integration step, I'm attempting to incorporate values for specific environments (think dev/staging/prod) from an external json file with limited setting values. An example of such a file is

```
{
    "DataServerUrl": "https://dev.server.addr.com",
    "ServerKey": "2a4d99233efea456b95114aa23ed342ae"
}
```

I can get to the data using jq. I can update the data using jq if I hard-code the updates. I'm looking for something general to take in any environment settings values and update them in the base settings file. My searches suggest I can do this in a single step without knowing the specific values. A command similar to

```
jq -r 'to_entries[]' settings.dev.json |
  while IFS= read -r key value; do
    jq -r '.[$key] |= [$value]' settings.json
  done
```

What happens is I get error messages stating `jq: error: $key is not defined at <top-level>` (as well as the same message for $value). The messages appear several times in pairs. settings.json is not changed. Now, this makes partial sense because the output from just `jq -r 'to_entries[]' settings.dev.json` looks like (empty space in this output is included as produced by the command).

```
 
  "key": "DataServerUrl",
  "value": "https://dev.server.addr.com"


  "key": "ServerKey",
  "value": "2a4d99233efea456b95114aa23ed342ae"
```

How do I go about iterating over the values in the environment settings file such that I can use those values to update the base settings file for further processing (i.e., publishing to the target environment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to provide both files and address the second one using `input`. That way, all you need is the assignment:

```sh
jq '.Settings = input' settings.json insert.json
```

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": "Warning"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "./logs/log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Settings": {
    "DataServerUrl": "https://dev.server.addr.com",
    "ServerKey": "2a4d99233efea456b95114aa23ed342ae"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7mlsvIi5YTb)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
jq -s '.[1] as $insert | .[0].Settings |= $insert | .[0]' settings.json insert.json
```

Where we :

- `slurp` both files
- Save `insert.json` to a variable called `$insert`
- Append (`|=`) `$insert` to `.[0].Settings`
- Show only the first file `.[0]`

So the output will become:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": "Warning"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "./logs/log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Settings": {
    "DataServerUrl": "https://dev.server.addr.com",
    "ServerKey": "2a4d99233efea456b95114aa23ed342ae"
  }
}
```